# how to get designed serial numbers of parts like "FrontFacingCameraModuleSerialNumber" but designed

Tags: libimobiledevice

how to get designed serial numbers of parts like "FrontFacingCameraModuleSerialNumber" but designed?

And second question:
how to get serial number of touchID?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. Maybe it will help other people.
I found a hash that works with iPhones <7 )
mobilegestalt jWdMTTxiAZc+KNO6Bz2jNg

Answer (score 0):

could you extract FrontFacingCameraModuleSerialNumber from AppleDiagnosticDataSysCfg

Comment: so, how to read AppleDiagnosticDataSysCfg?